# How can I allow a comma in a decimal number in a scaffolded MVC view?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller, decimal, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Database is MSSQL and project is ASP.NET MVC Core

I have a database which is filled with balls. Each ball has properties like size and weight. The weight property is a decimal value. I made a model called 'Ball' and added the properties to it. I used the scaffolding function in Visual Studio to generate a controller with views. I linked the database and it all works!

The issue is, when adding a ball to the list, I cant add a comma to the decimal value. I can add a dot to the number, but this doesnt get saved as a decimal.

When I enter `4.56` in the textbox the database saves it as `456,00`.

How can I fix this issue. I think I have to change the validation, but I am not sure where, since Im new to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This *sounds* like you are passing your parameters as strings not as decimal values. Regardless of the language setting, `4.56` is interpreted by T-SQL as "Four point five six".

Comment: Would be good to see the database schema as that sounds a bit confusing.  if you enter 4.56 then it will save it as that if it is a decimal